# Pharo add configurations to startup preferences

Tags: smalltalk, pharo

I'd like to add some configuration to the startup-pref.st file so that they will be loaded automatically whenever I download a new version of pharo.

Specifically I would like to download my projects repositories from smalltalkhub, so that I don't have to do it manually every time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you should have a look at my automatic setup gists: https://gist.github.com/Uko/7672537

There is a file called `installDFlow.st` that installs *DFlow* project. In a same way you can install whatever you want. These files have to be put into ~/Library/Preferences/pharo/

Comment: If I am right this would require that I create some configurations fwith Metacello for my projects. Is it the "Versionner" tool the right way to do?

Comment: @LorenzoBaracchi never used _Versioner_. Check out http://sleepycoders.blogspot.ch/2013/10/dead-simple-intro-to-metacello.html